# how to replace python 32-bits with 64-bits without losing my projects?

Tags: python, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am using python 32-bits but I want to upgrade it to 64-bit to use some advanced modules.
But I don't want to lose my 32-bit projects, suggest help, please.

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522943/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-a-portable-python-32-bit-install-to-a-64-bit-install#:~:text=No%2C%20it%20is%20not%20possible,installed%20packages%20and%20their%20versions.

Comment: thanks but no, i wanna keep my projects not my packages/libraries

Comment: Then define "projects" please. Precompiled python extensions (aka packages/libraries) would seem to be the only problem for me, too - plain python source code should run just fine.

Comment: So you mean that my codes won't be deleted nor no longer working if i download python 64?

Comment: Thanks for everyone who replied!

Answer (score 1):

Pure Python code is neither 32 nor 64 bits, because Python is a very high level programming language. When you run a Python program, the Python interpreter quickly compiles your source code to machine code and executes it.

It doesn't matter whether you use a 32 bit or 64 bit Python interpreter to execute your pure Python program, because the result should be the same. However, if your program uses libraries that contain non-Python code, you might have to reinstall the 64 bit version of those libraries.

So to conclude, don't be afraid to download and install the 64 bit version of Python because your Python programs will all run perfectly on it!